# Нахождение положительных пиков функции

Tags: python, алгоритм, обработка-сигналов

[image: график]

Требуется программно найти количество и местоположение положительных пиков на графике.
Известно, что количество пиков нечетное. Обычно 3, 5 или 7. В данном случае 3. Также известно, что за каждым положительным пиком следует отрицательный.
Как лучше решить такую проблему на Python? Желательно без подбора коэффициентов
**Дополнение**: Данные всегда начинаются с положительного пика и заканчиваются отрицательным.
Данные представляют собой вертикальную проекцию изображения, обработанную функцией `np.gradient(projection)/projection`. То есть отношение второй производной функции к её высоте.

Comment: Искать надо в наборе данных или на изображении?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что это полученный откуда-то сигнал (а не функция)? Может ли этот сигнал начинаться с отрицательного пика или всегда только с положительного? Нужен алгоритм или особенности его реализации на Python?

Comment: Искать в дискретном наборе данных. Хотелось бы решить эту задачу основываясь на функциях из scipy или любой другой крупной и отлаженной библиотеки. Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поскольку просто локальный экстремум не устраивает, надо добавить проверку превышения порога для отбраковки мелких пиков и артефактов. Порог можно вычислить как [СКО](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) выборки, умноженное на некоторую константу, соответствующую доверительному интервалу для математического ожидания.
На практике эту константу принимают равной `2.5`.

**UPD**
С учётом дополнительных условий задачи пиком следует считать максимум на отрезке от "верха" (начальной точки или первого значения выше `q`) до "низа" (первого значения ниже `-q`).
При этом для массива размерности `n` возможен следующий алгоритм:

1. Найти СКО выборки и вычислить порог `q`.
2. Положить `top=0`.
3. Найти координату `bottom` первой точки отрезка `[top, n-1]` со значением меньше `-q`. Если такой точки нет, перейти к п.7.
4. Найти координату максимума на отрезке `[top, bottom-1]`. Если значение максимума больше `q`, записать его в массив пиков.
5. Найти координату `top` первой точки отрезка `[bottom+1, n-1]` со значением больше `q`. Если такой точки нет, перейти к п.7.
6. Перейти к п.3.
7. Использовать массив пиков.

Comment: А как учитывать чередуемость пиков?

Comment: @Oceinic Уточнил

Answer (score 5):

Ничего лучшего, чем  поиск пиков в массиве в голову не приходит. Строгое чередование положительных и отрицательных пиков облегчает задачу.

Т.е. алгоритм примерно такой.
Выбираем значения двух порогов: положительного и отрицательного. Ищем максимум пока сигнал больше отрицательного порога. Найденный максимум и есть пик, а индекс в массиве - его позиция. Ждем превышения положительного порога и ищем очередной положительный пик. Пороги подбираются так, чтобы быть выше шума: колебания около нуля. Их значения могут быть ясны исходя из природы сигнала (минимально возможная величина пика), либо можно попытаться их вычислить статистически (найти среднеквадратическое отклонение шума и установить порог в значение, например 3 СКО).
Боюсь, что готовой функции в библиотеках не будет. Однако реализация такого алгоритма тривиальна. К сожалению, с Python мало знаком, поэтому приведу возможную реализацию на C++ (думаю, что проблем с пониманием возникнуть не должно):

```
typedef double sample_type;
struct Peak {
    sample_type magnitude;
    std::size_t pos;
};
std::vector<Peak> peaks(const std::vector<sample_type> &sig) {
    static sample_type threshold_lo = -0.05;
    static sample_type threshold_hi = 0.05;
    std::vector<Peak> ret_peaks;
    std::vector<sample_type>::size_type isample = 0;
    while (1) {
        while ((isample < sig.size()) && (sig[isample] < threshold_hi)) {
            ++isample;
        }
        if (isample >= sig.size())
            break;
        ret_peaks.push_back(Peak(sig[isample], isample));
        while ((isample < sig.size()) && (sig[isample] > threshold_lo)) {
            if (sig[isample] > ret_peaks.back().magnitude) {
                ret_peaks.back().magnitude = sig[isample];
                ret_peaks.back().pos = isample;
            }
            ++isample;
        }
        if (isample >= sig.size())
            break;
    }
    return ret_peaks;
}
```

Можно также использовать [корреляцию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) (для ее вычисления должна быть готовая функция в scipy). Но, на мой взгляд, в данном случае это более сложный подход. О корреляции можно также почитать [здесь](http://www.dspguide.com/ch7/3.htm)