# Надо получить те значения массива которые соответствуют "горкам" и желательно индекс. Как мне лучше это реализовать?

Tags: c#, математика, обработка-сигналов

У меня есть массив, по ним я построил график, теперь мне надо получить те значения
которые соответствуют "горкам" и желательно индекс. Как мне лучше это реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, что здесь не помешает добавить какие-то метки связанные с математикой и/или обработкой сигналов, возможно тогда ответ будет получен вами быстрее. Навскидку, экстремумы ищут в нулях первой производной (`f'[t]=(f[t]-f[t-1])/delta`), горки - там, где она при переходе нуля меняет знак с "+" на "-". Но сначала, скорее всего, сделать какую-нибудь сглаживающую фильтрацию.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд ничего лучшего, чем решение "в лоб" здесь нет.
В сигнале присутствуют импульсы, большие нуля. Их нужно искать.
Таким образом, для поиска "горба":

1. Задаем порог, по превышению которого будем считать, что значение в сигнале отличается нуля (например, 0.1).
2. Задаем порог для допустимой неравномерности импульса (например, 0.01).
3. Задаем минимальную длительность импульса (например, 30с).
4. Находим последовательные значения сигнала, отвечающие условиям из пп. 1-3 (например, значения колеблются в интервале 0.948..0.950 более 30с) - это начало импульса.
5. Находим значение, меньшее порога из п. 1 - это конец импульса.
6. Повторяем пп. 4-5 для поиска следующего импульса.

Comment: А можно код  пож-та

Comment: @SVD102 Код писать не готов - на мой взгляд, в приведенном алгоритме достаточно информации для его реализации. Если что-то непонятно - могу пояснить. Также был похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/493973/201103. В ответах на этот вопрос есть примеры кода.